# How to add the containing folder of a file to Future Access List

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

Let's say a folder ***some_folder*** contains a file called ***some_file.mp4***.
When I pick *some_file.mp4* using `FileSavePicker`, is it possible to add *some_folder* to the `FutureAccessList`?

**Note:**

1. I know I can add a folder to future access list by getting that folder by `FolderPicker` but I don't want to open the picker again , as the `FileOpenPicker` has already opened once before. I need to create some other files in that directory.
2. without using *BroadFileSystem Access*, that's the last option for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. You can't get any more rights than user gave you and user did not give you such a right by the action that you describe and with the limitations that you have described.

You probably need to use `FolderPicker` and to ask for the file name in some custom dialog after that.

If even that is not an option you need to look for alternatives that are possible like using WPF instead of UWP.

Comment: I've thought of custom dialog, but was curious if the thing I asked for was possible by any means. Thanks.

Comment: Other alternatives are:
(a) declare 'broadFileSystemAccess' capability - or  

(b) add a desktop extension full trust process to your UWP (which has full file access by default) and handle the file access operations from there